# Color scheme + verb

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Is it correct to say "The color scheme of the pattern is made in different shades of blue and green."?

Or it's better to say: the color scheme uses/includes/consists of?
Which option is preferable?

Thank you

Comment: A colour scheme is the combination of colours chosen by a designer, so I would use _consists of_ or simply _is_.

Comment: You obviously mean ***made up of*** instead. That should work. Good Luck.

Answer (score -1):

A colour scheme (also called palette) is a choice of colours, so it's not *made of* nor does it *use* anything.

You could say 'the colour scheme *comprises* different shades of blue and green'.

*Consists of* will also work, as pointed out by Kate Bunting above.

If you say '*includes*', that would suggest to me that there are other colours in the scheme besides greens and blues, but for some reason you choose to highlight the greens and blues.